# SELECT WHERE IN in node-mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-mysql

Does anyone know how to use `SELECT WHERE IN` in node-mysql?

I've tried the code below, but I get the following error message:

```
'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(`PHP`,`apache`)'' at line 1'
```

This is my code:

```
whereIn = '(';
for ( var i in tagArray ) {
    if ( i != tagArray.length - 1 ) {
        whereIn += "`" + tagArray[i] + "`,";    
    }else{
        whereIn += "`" + tagArray[i] + "`"; 
    }
}
whereIn += ')';

console.log(whereIn);

client.query(
    'SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_name IN ?',
    [whereIn],
    function(err, result, fields) {
        client.destroy();

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log(result);

        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

Comment: Don't you love SQL error messages? Soooo0o0o0oo helpful

Answer (score 19):

You have to use `IN (?)` and NOT `IN ?`.

Any string manipulation may result in a SQL INJECTION backdoor.

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to pass the `tagArray` of values to node-mysql and it will handle the rest for you:

```
client.query(
    'SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_name IN (?)',
    [tagArray],
    function(err, result, fields) {
        client.destroy();

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log(result);

        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

For more information, see the section in the manual for how different values are automatically escaped: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote your strings, not use backticks.

```
whereIn = '(';
for ( var i in tagArray ) {
    if ( i != tagArray.length - 1 ) {
        whereIn += "'" + tagArray[i] + "',";    
    }else{
        whereIn += "'" + tagArray[i] + "'"; 
    }
 }
whereIn += ')';
```

Comment: Yes, backticks are not for values.

Comment: Ive tried that already, and I get this,

'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(\'PHP\',\'apache\',\'Java\')'' at line 1'

:(

Comment: Looks like your query is automatically escaping quotes. Is there an option that will NOT escape them?

Comment: wont there be a security problem if it's not escaped?

Comment: You want to escape any quotes inside of tagArray, but not the quotes outside of each of the values.

Comment: i got it by doing this

 var sql = new String();
 sql = 'SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_name IN (';
 for ( var i in tagArray ) {
  tagArray[i] = client.escape(tagArray[i]);
  if ( i != tagArray.length - 1 ) {
   sql += tagArray[i] + ",";    
  }else{
   sql += tagArray[i]; 
  }
  }
 sql += ')';

 console.log(sql);

 client.query(
  sql,
  function(err, result, fields) {
   client.destroy();

   if (err) {
    throw err;
   }

   console.log(result);

   res.redirect('/');
  }
 );

Comment: Most SQL systems only allow parameter substitution where an identifier would normally be allowed; a WHERE list isn't an identifier. I vaguely remember that Mysql has some sort of extension function that allows you to achieve the same effect using a different syntax; I think it came up here sometime in the last few months.

Answer (score 1):

For a more secure solution that avoids having to escape values, use ? params like you would normally do, but create the param placeholders dynamically like this:

```
var inlist = '';
for(var i=0; i<ids.length; i++) {
  inlist += '?,';
}
inlist = inlist.substring(0,inlist.length-1);

var sql = 'SELECT a, b, c FROM mytable WHERE id in (' + inlist + ')';

conn.query( sql, ids, function(err, rows) {
  . . .
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for answer to this in 2021.

```
 client.query(
      'SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_name IN (?)', 
       [['val1', 'val2']],
       function(err, result, fields) {
    client.destroy();

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log(result);

    res.redirect('/');
}
```

);

Answer (score -1):

A working solution:

```
client.query(
    'SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_name IN ?',
    [tagArray],
    function(err, result, fields) {
        client.destroy();

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        console.log(result);

        res.redirect('/');
    }
);
```

No need to manually wrap tagArray in quotes. It is escaped by the mysql module.

Comment: You should add brackets to ?: 'SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag_name IN (?)',